# What draft does java-websocket's WebSocketServer use?

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I can't figure out from the [WebSocketServer.java source](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/server/WebSocketServer.java) which draft it uses.

The WebSocketClient.java can use RFC 6455, Hybi 17, Hybi 10, Hixie 76, and Hixie 75 yet [defaults to RFC 6455](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/7c3b223536dc8bd4e8794ac265ad06679583e30f/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java#L61-64).

What draft does java-websocket's WebSocketServer use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It supports whatever drafts you want it to support.

The constructor supports passing in a list of Drafts that you want the server to handle.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/server/WebSocketServer.java#L131-L150

Looks like it will always support Version 13 (RFC-6455) even if you pass in an empty Drafts list ([as a null list will result](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/WebSocketImpl.java#L114-L115) in [all 4 default Drafts](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/WebSocketImpl.java#L52-L57) being active), otherwise it has 4 drafts implemented for you to pick / choose / limit from.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/tree/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/drafts

- Draft_17 = `Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13` (aka RFC-6455)
- Draft_10 = `Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8`
- Draft_76 = `Sec-WebSocket-Version` (unspecified, pre-versioning, Hixie-76)
- Draft_75 = `Sec-WebSocket-Version` (unspecified, pre-versioning, Hixie-75)

**Update: March 2013**

As of Jetty 9.x, only RFC6455 (`Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13`) is supported.  All support for draft versions of WebSocket have been dropped.

Comment: Thank you so much Joakim Erdfelt!  It was late, and I definitely asked that question poorly, so thank you so much for answering this question in every possible way!