# Web Socket Connection failed from Android Client

Tags: android, mobile, websocket

I am developing an Android client for a server where the requirement is continuous exchange of audio stream to the WebSockets-based server.

While connection with web sockets the android client throws the following error.

> Closed draft org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_10@b2fe9b40 refuses
>   handshake

But I tried with following web socket uri. Connection getting succeeded. 
ws://echo.websocket.org

> **Code**:

```
URI uri;
    try {
        // uri = new URI(
        // "ws://echo.websocket.org");
        uri = new URI(
                "ws://serverIP:9090/WebRtc/serverendpoint");

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
            mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " "
                    + Build.MODEL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            final String message = s;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
                    textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mWebSocketClient.connect();
```

I tried the echo test from browser for the web socket(ws://serverIP:9090/WebRtc/serverendpoint) I have used. It's getting connected properly. 
But When I try that from both mobile or emulator, nothing works.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Could you please tell me what worked for you. I am getting same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue with this.

Actually the problem with the Java provided web socket jar file.

Instead of that I have used the 
***Autobahn*** (Android Specific Web Socket Open Source https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid).

Now am able to connect with the web socket server.

Comment: yeah same here: I tried to use org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0 but that socket cannot communicate with Java EE server endpoints

Answer (score 20):

I just found another simple way to get rid of this issue.

Change following line

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri){
```

to

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_17()){
```

I found the hint in my Serverlogs which said:

> User Agent: [unset] requested WebSocket version [8], Jetty supports version: [13]

As you can see in the link below, Version 8 is Draft_10, Version 13 is Draft_17.

[Link to supported Websocket-Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045261/4791726)

Comment: I am facing the same issue...
but your solution is not working for me

Comment: @JayVyas Is your Logcat output the same?

Comment: Have a look at your Serverlog. Maybe you need to choose another draft.

Comment: Guys, this was the issue, When we use host having proper domain like ws://echo.websocket.org it work without Draft_17 but when we use an ip url so we have to use Draft_17

Comment: I am getting similar issue but the above solution is not working for me